# POST variables to php from Obj-c its doesnt work

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode

Hello Im newbie with iOS and Xcode, but I have to do a login screen,and that login screen don't response me anything after try connect the php on server.

```
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {


    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {

        if([[self.insUsuario text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.insSenha text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

            [self alertStatus:@"Insira o email e a senha!" :@"Erro" :0];

        } else {
            //ViewPontos *WP = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewPontos"];
            //WP.gUser = self.insUsuario.text;

            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"usuario=%@&senha=%@",[self.insUsuario text],[self.insSenha text]];

            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://emporio56/apiapp/pegarPontos.php"];

            //NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSLog(@"DATA %@", postData);

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

            NSLog(@"%@", request);

            NSURLConnection *conn= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            if(conn)
            {

                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
                NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

                if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
                {
                    //NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                   NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", response);

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                    success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                    NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    } else {

                        NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                        [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Erro" :0];
                    }

                } else {
                    //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    [self alertStatus:@"Erro!" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }


                NSLog(@"Conectado");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Nao conectou");
            }
            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Erro" :0];
    }
    if (success) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
        // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
        // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
        // also serves to clear it
        _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
        [_responseData appendData:data];
    }

    - (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                      willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
        // Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
        return nil;
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        // The request is complete and data has been received
        // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now

    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        // The request has failed for some reason!
        // Check the error var
    }
```

after run the code to test and put the username and password, I don't get response from the server its always `response = (null)`, someone knows what can I do to fix it? because Ive tried the most of codes that can you find in the web and it didn't work as well how the people say, I using the same php to connect an android application but it works, so what Im doing wrong on my code to POST the username and password on the php file and connect to the db.

Sorry for the problem, but I don't know what is happened

Comment: Why don't you try to use Alamofire ? As new developer it can wrap a lot of functionalities for you

Comment: @GIJOW but Alamofire dont is only to Swift codes?

Comment: You can use AFNetworking

Comment: This one  https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking ?

Comment: Yes. The only one. Same brave Alamofire's team

Comment: Ok, now I have to see how can I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. Hope it will solve your problem.

```
NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://emporio56/apiapp/pegarPontos.php?usuario=%@&senha=%@",[self.insUsuario text],[self.insSenha text]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *dicYourResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
             NSLog(@"%@",dicYourResponse);
         }
     }];
```

Comment: oh yes, I've made in other way but this codes works too